# No permission to access invitable friends

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

I am developing an android game app and want to get a list of Facebook invitable friends.

Unfortunately I hit this error: `Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) No permission to access invitable_friends.}` with code below.

**Code**

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/invitable_friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback()
    {
         @Override
         public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response)
         {
             System.out.println(response);
         }
     }
).executeAsync();
```

**Permissions**

```
List< String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_friends");
```

Can anyone helps me to point out the problems ? Is it caused by missing permission ? 
Or, I can only get invitable_friends for my game app with Canvas implemenation ?

Thank You. :)

Comment: Which facebook sdk versio you use ?

Comment: @MeryamAlaoui, version 4.18.0

Comment: Yes, you need to have the Canvas platform set up. (And if you do that, you will need a _playable_ version of your game on canvas, otherwise it will be rejected in review.)

Comment: @CBroe, from your point of view, is it got any alternative way in retrieving list of Facebook friends ?

Comment: Do you want to invite people, or do you just want the list of friends?

Comment: @CBroe, I need both of it. I need a page to view all my Facebook friends, and another page for app invitation

Comment: Well you can’t get all friends, only friends that are also using your app and have also granted user_friends permission. (invitable_friends is for the purpose of inviting friends only, you are _not_ allowed to use it to show a list of friends to the user for any other purpose.)

Comment: @CBroe, if let say I want a list of friends for invitation purpose, am I needed to submit to Facebook review ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133878/discussion-between-w-l-wong-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

Getting `user_friends` permission requires you to submit your app for facebook devs to review. If you just want the list of friends **who have installed your app** you can get that without the `user_friends` permission, by just doing a get call on :

> https://graph.facebook.com/fb_id/friends?access_token=...

Reference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Comment: _“Getting `user_friends` permission requires you to submit your app for facebook devs to review”_ - no, it doesn’t; `user_friends` is one of the three basic permissions that are approved by default.

Comment: _“If you just want the list of friends who have installed your app you can get that without the user_friends permission”_ – that’s not true either. You need user_friends from the current app user, otherwise you can not read their friends at all. And only friends who are also users of the app and have also granted the permission on their end will show in the list.