# No permission to access invitable friends facebook

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read `invitable_friends` using `me/invitable_friends` endpoint.

Here is what I am getting:
[image]

Here are the properties of my user token:
[image]

I suspect that something is wrong with my user token. May it be the case or are there are other problems possible?

I saw [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41805289/no-permission-to-access-invitable-friends) question. The app is submitted and approved, so the answer does not help.

May it be that the problem is about `Graph API` version?

Will appreciate any help provided.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/invitable_friends) is a very interesting thing. It is said: `This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be accessed.`. May it be the reason of me getting: `No permission to access invitable friends facebook`?

Comment: So basically your question is, "Why can't I use this deprecated feature?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#invitable-friends-4-4

> **Invitable Friends API**
>
> GET operations on the /user/invitable_friends
>   edge will now return an empty data set. The edge will be removed
>   entirely in the near future.